# bochs-2.2.6:error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: macos, gcc, config

The error occurred when I was trying to configure bochs-2.2.6 on my macOS High Sierra. Here's the error part in config.log:

```
configure:2132: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2135: gcc -pipe -O3 -I/sw/include -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-      functions -falign-loops=16 -falign-jumps=16 -falign-functions=16 -falign-labels=16 -falign-loops-max-skip=15 -falign-jumps-max-skip=15 -fprefetch-loop-arrays  -fpascal-strings -fno-common -arch ppc -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Dmacintosh  -fpascal-strings -fno-common -arch ppc -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Dmacintosh -L/sw/lib conftest.c  >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-falign-loops-max-skip=15'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-falign-jumps-max-skip=15'
clang: warning: optimization flag '-falign-loops=16' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-falign-jumps=16' is not supported [-  Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-falign-functions=16' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-falign-labels=16' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
clang: warning: optimization flag '-fprefetch-loop-arrays' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]
configure:2138: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2177: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The version of gcc on this machine is 4.2.1. And I checked my command line tools. They are of the latest version.

Comment: Please make clear what your question is. 1) Do you want someone to tell you how
you might overcome this particular `./configure` error? Or 2) Do you want someone to tell
you how you can successfully build bochs-2.2.6 on MacOS High Sierra (i.e. solving
this problem and any subsequent ones that are then revealed)?

Comment: Sorry for not making question clear. Temporarily I want to know how to overcome this configuration error.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, `gcc` is by default an alias for `clang`, the [LLVM C Compiler](https://clang.llvm.org/).
You may have gcc 4.2.1 installed on your system, but the diagnostic:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-falign-loops-max-skip=15'
```

shows that C compiler you are invoking is in fact clang. `-falign-loops-max-skip`
is not a commandline option for clang. Nor is it an option for any mainline
version of GCC since 4.4.7 - as far back as I can readily check.

There is [evidence from 2006](https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/flags/CPU2006_flags.20090714.11.html) that `-falign-loops-max-skip` was an option for gcc 4.1
and gcc 4.2, though it's not backed up by [the official 4.1 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary).
Also [evidence](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/52766554/) that the option was supported by `llvm-gcc`, the Apple bootstrapping predecessor
of clang, which was based on gcc 4.2.

So the chances are not bad that your gcc 4.2 will recognize this option. Bochs 2.2.6,
released 2006, is contemporary with gcc 4.1, which also fits for it's use of the option.

I suppose you would prefer to stick with your uptodate gcc (alias clang) for
purposes other than building this very old bochs package. In that case you can
specify your gcc 4.2 as the C compiler to use just for building bochs via the
commandline of the `./configure` script. If your gcc 4.2 is installed as, say,
`/usr/local/bin/gcc-4`, then run:

```
./configure CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4 [...]
```

where `[...]` is whatever other options, if any, you were passing anyhow.

This may well get you over that `./configure` error, but I would not be
at all surprised if fixing that problem exposes the next one.